# Postgres triggers

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I would like to know which table stores the create statement of a trigger eg

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_update_sal
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON employees
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE t_update_sal_v1();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`information_schema.triggers` only stores part of the trigger definition.

You can get the complete SQL for the trigger using `pg_get_triggerdef()`:

```
select trg.tgname, 
       pg_catalog.pg_get_triggerdef(trg.oid, true)
from pg_trigger trg
  join pg_class tbl on trg.tgrelid = tbl.oid
  join pg_namespace sch on tbl.relnamespace = sch.oid
where tbl.relname = 'employees'
  and sch.nspname = 'public'
order by 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can dig that information on `information_schema.triggers`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no table that stores the "create statement" for a trigger as such. The SQL is parsed, executed and discarded.

`pg_dump` re-constructs the statement from the system catalogs: primarily `pg_catalog.pg_trigger`, with additional information fetched from `pg_class`, `pg_attribute`, `pg_namespace`, etc.

As Soni points out, there's a user-friendly interface for this in the `information_schema.triggers` view.